# How to know if user is logged with google or facebook using passport.js?

Tags: passport.js, passport-facebook, passport-google-oauth

It easy to find if user is logged in. But how can I check if user is logged with specific oauth client?. ex. Google or Facebook

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check with perticuler IDs and for more see here

https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

http://mherman.org/blog/2013/11/10/social-authentication-with-passport-dot-js/#.VjbvGVUrLIU